# Having problems with "OnCollisionEnter2D" in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this code:

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class CollisionPlayer : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public bool alreadyDied = false;
 
     public GameObject player;
 
     public float timeDeath;
 
     public ParticleSystem particles;
 
     public GameObject explosionGO;
 
     private SpriteRenderer sr;
 
     private BoxCollider2D bc;
 
     private PlayerController walkScript;
 
     void Start()
     {
         sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
 
         bc = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
 
         walkScript = GetComponent<PlayerController>();
     }
 
     void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collide)
     {
         if (collide.gameObject.CompareTag("Dead"))
         {
             Instantiate(particles, player.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
 
             Instantiate(explosionGO, player.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
 
             CinemachineShake.Instance.ShakeCamera(30f, .1f);
 
             alreadyDied = true;
         }
     }


 void Update()
 {
     if(alreadyDied == true)
     {
         timeDeath -= Time.deltaTime;
         sr.enabled = false;
         bc.enabled = false;
         walkScript.enabled = false;
     }

     if(timeDeath <= 0)
     {
         SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
     }
 }
  }
```

This is the bullet's code:

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;

 public class LeftBulletScript : MonoBehaviour
 {
 // Start is called before the first frame update
 public float speed;
 public float destructionLeftTime;

 public ParticleSystem particles;

 private GameObject thisGameObject;

 void Start()
 {
     thisGameObject = this.gameObject;
     Destroy(gameObject, destructionLeftTime);
 }

 void Update()
 {
     transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);

     if(destructionLeftTime > 0.05f)
     {
         destructionLeftTime -= Time.deltaTime;
     }
     else 
     {
         Instantiate(particles, thisGameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
     }
 }
}
```

This code should spawn some particles and a sound effect when the player gets hit by something with tag "Dead". But that does not happen. I have a box collider 2D on both the bullet (that should kill me) and the player. My Rigidbody2D is dynamic on the player with z freezed. The bullet does not have a rigidbody. I made sure that the bullet actually has the tag "Dead", spelled the exact same way as the way I wrote on the script. The weirdest thing is that I used this code on another game and nothing changed (just the name of a script). Both the player and the bullet are on the same layer. Anyone could tell me what could have happened?

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Put a break point in OnCollisionEnter2D and see what is happening.

Comment: ok, I was being dumb because I did not put anything on the Inspector and the order of the code caused me some problems.